# Add extra information to all python exceptions

Tags: python, oop, exception, decorator

After another terrible bug hunt, I am wondering the following:
Is it possible to add some extra information to all exceptions, for example the name of an object. 
This would increase the readability of the errors a lot and make looking for bugs (or input errors) a lot quicker. This is especially the case if one has many objects which are from the same class and therefore share much code, but have different attributes. In this case it can be very useful if the error message also states the name of the object in the error.

A simplfied example: I am trying to simulate different types of facilities, a pig farm and a cow farm. These are the same class, but do have different attributes. In the simulation many facilities are made and if an exception is raised, it would be very helpful if the name of the object is added to the exception.

```
class facility():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.animals = []

farms = []
farms.append(facility('cow_farm'))
farms.append(facility('pig_farm'))
print farms[0].stock
```

This would yield

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: facility instance has no attribute 'stock'
```

But I would like to add the name of the facility:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: facility instance has no attribute 'stock'
  Name of object: cow_farm
```

I tried something like

```
def print_name(exception):
    try:
        print self.name
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    raise exception

@print_name
Exception
```

But that doesn't work. Is it possible to do such a thing, or are there good reasons not to do this?

Comment: You're going to be limited by the fact that most objects don't have a `name` attribute. What exactly would you like to see if an `IndexError` occurs somewhere random in your code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle errors and add information, you could do it as follows:

```
farm = farms[0]
try:
    print farm.stock
except AttributeError:
    raise AttributeError("{} has no attribute 'stock'".format(farm.name))
```

However, it might be wiser to add the empty `stock` in `__init__` to avoid this error.

You should [never use a bare `except`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/), as it hides useful information from you (*particularly* when developing and debugging!) Generally, each `try` block should be as short as possible, preferably doing only one thing. If multiple errors could stem from a single `try` block, you can add multiple handlers:

```
try:
    print farm.stock["hay"]
except AttributeError:
    raise AttributeError("{} has no attribute 'stock'".format(farm.name))
except KeyError:
    raise KeyError("{} has no 'hay' in 'stock'".format(farm.name))
```

(Although note that adding `self.stock` in `__init__` and checking `if "hay" in farm.stock:` would save you from this error handling.)

If an error happens that you weren't expecting, it is generally best for that error to propagate up the call stack until it is explicitly handled or you get to see it. Otherwise, you are heading for this foolish anti-pattern:

```
def some_func(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # all of some_func's content goes here
    except:
        raise Exception("Something went wrong in some_func().")
```

Which is no use to you and extremely frustrating for anyone trying to use your code.

If you want to handle `AttributeError`s like this at the `class` level, you could do:

```
class Facility(object):

    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        """Called on attempt to access attribute instance.key."""
        if key not in self.__dict__:
            message = "{} instance '{}' has no attribute '{}'."
            message = message.format(type(self).__name__,
                                     self.name, key)
            raise AttributeError(message)
        else:
            return self.__dict__[key]
```

Then you will get

```
>>> farm = Facility("pig farm")
>>> print farm.stock
...
"AttributeError: Facility instance 'pig farm' has no attribute 'stock'."
```

If you want to use this pattern with multiple classes, you can make a superclass:

```
class ProtectedAttrs(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        ...

class Facility(ProtectedAttrs):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Facility, self).__init__(name)
        self.animals = []
```

This sort of thing will work for some types of error. However, I am not aware of any general way to handle *all* errors with references to the instance involved.

Comment: Ah, was beaten to it!

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a more general solution, which incorporates also the unexpected exceptions.
For example if the facility has a function which can raise an exception, or if an IndexError occurs, etc.

Comment: I have edited my answer to expand on error handling practices. If the error isn't expected, how would you know how best to describe it?

Comment: The error should propagate up the call stack, but when I see it, I would like to see if the cow_farm or the pig_farm has raised the error. When there are a hundred different facilities in the program, it is difficult to find the right one when the error message only states that a facility instance has raised the error. And preferably I would like to do so without using a try-except clause every time I call a facility.

Comment: I have added more to my answer, which will handle the `AttributeError` correctly.

Comment: That last option is the one I would like to avoid, therefore I was hoping for a way to add an object description.

Comment: The reason this is difficult is that, generally, *it isn't the instance's fault it doesn't contain what you want*. By 'looking before you leap' (e.g. `if key not in self.__dict__:`, `if index < len(self.animals):`) and initialising your instances sensibly (e.g. setting `self.stock = {}` in `__init__()`) you can avoid many of these errors before they occur.

Comment: The option with catching all errors is exactly the one I would like to avoid;) Therefore I was hoping for a way to add an object description to the exception. It is a good idea to add it to the __getattr__ function, but I'm afraid a general solution is not possible.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to add some text to **all** exceptions like the OP asked.

Answer (score -1):

Most of exceptions contain *message* attribute, that give you additional information about error

```
In [163]: try:
   .....:     farm = []
   .....:     farm.stock
   .....: except AttributeError as err:
   .....:     print err.message
   .....:     
'list' object has no attribute 'stock'
```

Exception traceback points you to a code line, so usually it is not hard to figure out the problem

Comment: This tells you the name of the class, but *not* of the instance, which is what the OP wants

Comment: If you get an exception that your code cannot handle - it is a bug and you have to debug it anyway. So you will go to the code and you'll see which object caused the problem. If the exception is expected and handled - you don't really care about object entity. I find it absolutely redundant to invest in adding info that is mostly clear when you look at the code.

Comment: From the code you can see which object is causing the exception, but not which instance. This can be very valuable information.

Comment: .... which you mat get from the variables in the code block. If you have only one instance, specifying in your message that it has caused exception sort of absolutely useless.